# A simple to-do list - complete item, slide up all items below

Tags: jquery, animation

**tl;dr After completing an item, I'd like all items and the list below to animate up and take it's place.**

Here is my jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mattermill/GRFFD/4/

I'm creating a basic to-do list to familiarize myself with jQuery and Ruby on Rails at the same time. For now I'm just working on the jQuery animations.

Currently it is made up of two lists: **incomplete items** and **complete items**. To complete an item, you simply click that item's text, it fades out and appends itself to the completed items list. I would like to have all of the items *below* that item, as well as the completed items list, to animate up to take the place of the recently completed item while the `fadeOut()` is happening.

Unfortunately, I don't even know where to begin. I had a little bit of luck with `nextAll()` but I don't think that's the way to go about this as it doesn't apply to the completed items list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just so happens that this is (almost) the default behavior of [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) while animating; just change:

```
item.fadeOut(300, function() {
```

To:

```
item.hide(300, function() {
```

**[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/GRFFD/6/)**

Unfortunately, that also animates the left and right padding, which looks bad. You can use [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) to explicitly specify the properties you want to change:

```
item.animate({height: 0, opacity: 0, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0}, 300, function() {
```

This looks the best out of all of them, but it has a problem: it doesn't automatically remove its properties when it's done. If you want them reset once the animation is complete, you'll have to do that manually:

```
item.css({height: '', opacity: '', paddingTop: '', paddingBottom: '');
```

**[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/GRFFD/15/)**

Comment: Thanks! For UX purposes, I'd like to show that the item is being completed before moving it to the bottom of the pile, so I modified it just a little for a cleaner result.

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/mattermill/GRFFD/27/)

Comment: @mattermill: Since animations queue, you [can reduce the amount of nesting of the callbacks](http://jsfiddle.net/GRFFD/28/).